# Using Cycles Render engine with AMD GPU crashes Blender 2.83.5

Tags: rendering

Very new to Blender. When rendering a project and attempting to switch rendering device to GPU Compute, the program "loads render kernels" for about a minute and then crashes. Using a GPU with a Radeon RX 5600XT chipset updated to the latest driver at the time of posting, with Blender 2.83.5 installed. I have heard of numerous potential solutions including using previous versions of blender and different rendering engines, but thought it would be best to ask separately.

All Components Listed are Recognized:

GPU: RX 5600XT

CPU: Ryzen 3600

Blender: 2.83.5

Answer (score -1):

As it turns out, Radeon GPUs have their own rendering engine for blender ([Download Link](https://www.amd.com/en/technologies/radeon-prorender-downloads)). While this is not an exact replica of Cycles, there are similarities that make it a potential substitute.